# how to make a call using SIP protocol or WebRTC technology in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, voip, phone-call

Considering the development of an application in React-Native or Flutter that allows the user to click a button and make a call (that goes through service like Twilio) and this redirects it by calling to another person.

I've been looking for examples with SIP or WebRTC integration but hasn't found a lot of guides so far.

is it possible to develop something like that?